# Python game show high score

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with the high score of my game show code that i wrote everything works but i can't get it to print the final score and it won't print out the high score when i call it can anyone take a look at the code and tell me what i did wrong? Thanks!

```
num_ques = 0
correct = 0
for question_object in questions:
    print(question_object["question"])
    for i, choice in enumerate(question_object["answers"]):
        print(str(i + 1) + ". " + choice)
    answer = input("Choose an answer 1-4:")
    num_ques = num_ques + 1
    if answer == question_object["correct"]:
        print("Bravo.  You're a nerd")
        correct = correct + 1
        print("Your score is: %d/" % correct + str(num_ques))
    else:
        print("Your score is: %d/" % correct + str(num_ques))
        print("Well at least you have a life.")
```

Comment: what is the current output ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to change your prints. You have something like this:

```
print("Your score is: %d/" % correct + str(num_ques))
```

You are using 2 ways of concatenate. %d and '+'. You can concatenate using:

```
a='Hello'
b='World'
print a+b  #This would print 'HelloWorld'
```

but you can also do

```
print '%s%s' % (a,b)  #This would print 'HelloWorld' too
```

You can concatenate different types using that format like this:

```
a='I have'
b=1
c='year old.'
print '%s %d %s' % (a,b,c)  #This would print 'I have 1 year old'
```

For your code I see that you store the score of the player in the variable "correct", so to show "Your score is 7", the "7" is inside 'correct', and it is an integer. (If the variable you want to concatenate is a integer you use %d, if it is a string you use %s)

```
print "Your score is: %d" % (correct)
```

If you have more than one variable, something like "Your score is X/Y" assuming that X are the correct answers, and Y the total question answered:

```
print "Your score is %d/%d" % (correct, num_ques)
```

And you can concatenate as many variables as you want, the order of the %d and %s is the order of the variables between parentheses

To show a message with the final score, you can add a print when the for is ended that says something like:

```
print "Your final score is: %d!!!!!" % (correct)
```

To do this your code would be:

```
num_ques = 0
correct = 0
for question_object in questions:
    print(question_object["question"])
    for i, choice in enumerate(question_object["answers"]):
        print(str(i + 1) + ". " + choice)
    answer = input("Choose an answer 1-4:")
    num_ques = num_ques + 1
    if answer == question_object["correct"]:
        print "Bravo.  You're a nerd"
        correct = correct + 1
        print "Your score is: %d/%d" % (correct, num_ques)
    else:
        print "Your score is: %d/%d" % (correct, num_ques)
        print "Well at least you have a life."
print "Your final score is: %d/%d!!!!!" % (correct, num_quest)
```